# Like button data-href with IP address

Tags: facebook-like, ip, domain-name

We're struggling to get Like button working and we think it's because the use of an IP address rather than a domain name on data-href property. Is it true??

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://74.125.234.146" data-send="true" data-width="450" data-show-faces="false">
</div>
```

Once set the data-href property with a domain name it works pretty well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That is a Google IP is it not? Have you tried it with a domain name?

Comment: Yeah, it's just an example. As I wrote above, after set the domain name it works. Is there any restriction to set data-href with an IP address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that this is an old question, but I had this problem as well, and the solution is that facebook won't work together with IP address, only with a webpage with DNS or with a valid data-href (like http://example.com)

Answer (score 0):

I would say, given the research I have done, that there is no reason why it should not work.

[image: screenshot of developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/]

Source: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

However, given that it did not work for you in your tests, I would say there is no official restriction (that I could find), but it is not recommended (for recommendation's sake).

Comment: Did you try to generate the code? Even it's written "Note: The URLs in the code are protocol relative...Missing http and https in the code is intentional." if you specify just the IP address you'll get "The href entered is not recognized as a valid URL." like me.